# Website Printing Customization Possible?

Tags: css, printing

I have a website http://www.latrinidad.es
When I do a print out of a property, the website prints only two HUGE photos per page. Often I have 20 photos per apartment, so it mean there can be 10 pages of printing. But I need to reduce this!

Is there a way that the printout layout can be changed, so each page has perhaps 6 or 8 photos. Can it be customised so it prints perhaps a max of 10 photos etc etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use additional css style with **print** media query:

```
@media print {
    .myImage {width: 20%}
}
```

Or add additional css using another file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```